# In asp.net core mvc, the model binding for decimals does not accept thousand separators

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

For a model with a `decimal` property, if the value from client contains commas as thousand separator, the model binding will fail.

How can we solve this? Any solution (globally, controller/action local or model/property local) is good.

I have a workaround, which is to have a `string` property that reads and writes to the `decimal` one. But I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Does your application need to support both values with commas and points according the culture or you just one to support one format?

Comment: Currently, only comma as thousand separator is good

Answer (score 19):

If your application needs to support only a specific format (or culture), you could specify it in your `Configure` method as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

   [...]
}
```

If you want to support several cultures and to automatically select the right one for each request, you can use the localization middleware instead, e.g.:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    [...]  

    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("es"),
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        // Localized UI strings.
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2

**Edit - Decimal binder**

If everything above fails, you could also roll your own model binder, e.g.:

```
public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(decimal))
        {
            return new DecimalModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Remove unnecessary commas and spaces
        value = value.Replace(",", string.Empty).Trim();

        decimal myValue = 0;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(value, out myValue))
        {
            // Error
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                                    bindingContext.ModelName,
                                    "Could not parse MyValue.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(myValue);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the custom binder in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
 services.AddMvc((options) =>
 {
     options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
 });
```

Now every time you use a decimal type in any of your models, it will be parsed by your custom binder.

Comment: This does not work:

   `var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");`

   `cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";`

   `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;`

   `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;`

Comment: I don't need the decimal separator, I need 1234567 to be correctly parsed when sent like this: 1,234,567 i.e. Thousand separators

Comment: @Alireza If you don't need the decimal separator, can I ask why you're using the `decimal` datatype?

Comment: @mason I'm upgrading a project from asp.net mvc to core. The datatype is decimal, and currently does not need decimal separator, instead it needs thousand separators. I can live with a temporary solution that solves our current problem, but can fail against changing requirements.

Comment: @Alireza Then why not use an int if you don't need a decimal?

Comment: @mason I have many models with this problem, and I prefer to keep the core logic (non web code) as intact as possible. When I change a model, the change propagates into parts of the code I prefer to not touch. Again, I'm migrating a web-based project to asp.net core.

Comment: @Isma I have many complex models with this problem. My problem with your newer solution is that I have to re-create (and then maintain) the binder for each model. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check my last edit, I added a custom model binder that will work for any decimal type used in any of your models. That should do what you want, right?

Answer (score 1):

In case if localization and custom model binder didn't work for you, as it didn't for me. You can extend serialization settings with custom JsonConverter which will serialize and deseralize all decimal values.

```
private class CultureInvariantDecimalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //your custom parsing goes here
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(decimal) || objectType == typeof(decimal?));
    }
}
```

And apply it with with this extension method

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddInvariantDecimalSerializer(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CultureInvariantDecimalConverter()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the heart of this problem is the fact that decimal.TryParse() relies entirely on the local computer settings. No matter how many Decimal custom binders you code...
Example from the Custom Decimal Binder execution:
`value = "11.2"`
`?decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalValue)`
false
`value = "11,2"`
`?decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalValue)`
true
So even when the other commas is removed which seems its done by the native DecimalBinder then it still fails when it parses it to decimal in the tryparse method...
Use the tryparse method in this way:
`decimal.TryParse(value,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ,out decimalValue)`

Answer (score 0):

you must put CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when you want to convert double:

```
public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(double))
            {
                return new DoubleModelBinder();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (valueProviderResult == null)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            // Remove unnecessary commas and spaces
            value = value.Replace(",", string.Empty).Trim();

            double myValue = 0;
            try
            {
             myValue = Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(myValue);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch (Exception m)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;                
            }
           
        }
    }
```

and in startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
            });
```