# ASP.NET Core 7 razor pages validation problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, validation

I am learing and I have a small problem with my validation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fyzU.png)

In Denmark we are using , instead of . to dicimal numbers so when i a price like 7,99 it says it is not a number.

How can I fix this?

Bendix

I have tryed searching on it but I can't find anything helpfull on it

Comment: I'm not certain but you probably need to add [request localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or create a custom model binder for decimals.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169287/in-asp-net-core-mvc-the-model-binding-for-decimals-does-not-accept-thousand-sep) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-model-binder-sample) show custom model binding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.